# How to write comments in APEX classes?

Tags: apex, security-review, documentation

I'm wondering if there is a standard to write comments in APEX ?

In order to pass the Security Review, I review my code. And I think writing good comments in APEX classes can help the reviewers to understand the code.

For example, if we want to generate the Javadoc, we have to do something like this :

```
/**
 * Returns an ...
 * <p>
 * This method ... 
 *
 * @param  name  the name ...
 * @return      the string ...
 */
 public String myMethod(String name) {
        ...
 }
```

So does any comment standard like the code above exist ?

And does a tool to generate the documentation exist ?

Comment: See [Documenting Salesforce.com Apex class files](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/925/documenting-salesforce-com-apex-class-files). Having clear names for classes, methods and arguments (including test cases) gets you a fair way to understandable code, and the documentation shouldn't just duplicate what is already clear from the code. (Remember that anyone looking at your code is seeing both the code and the comments unlike for Javadoc where often API documentation is looked at in isolation.) I would focus on the class-level comments more than the method-level comments.

Comment: Ok, so you think I just have to write some comments on the source code and not include them in the documentation ?

Comment: Its a while since I did a security review, but I didn't supply any separate Javadoc-style documentation. See what others think though. Helping the reviewer understand your code through overview documentation of some sort certainly makes sense.

Comment: Are comments actually necessary for a security review? Aren't these done automatically through code parsers? Like checking if test class has assert statements or 'with sharing' in a class?

Comment: I don't really know if comments are mandatory but I think it's better, not only for reviewers but also for our developers team, to have a well-commented code.

Comment: While it's certainly an interesting question, you're asking around best practises which may differ between company culture or methodology. That's a very broad and subjective question which may be best discussed at different fora. Please keep in mind that a stackexchange site is focused and aimed at specific questions which can be answered without debate or subjectivity.

Comment: I don't think so. At my question `So does any comment standard like the code above exist ?`, I'm expecting an answer like `Yes it exists` or `No`. It doesn't depend on `company culture` or anything else.

Comment: I think if you reword your question to focus on whether there is any way to use JavaDoc style comments to get self-documenting code, you will have a more targeted question. Apex2Doc is probably the right answer to that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apex2Doc](http://code.google.com/p/apexdoc/) is similar to JavaDoc. Not necessary for security review, I don't think. But useful for the next person to edit your code.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in support for JavaDoc style comments in Apex, nor are they required for the security review.

[ApexDoc](https://code.google.com/p/apexdoc/) is a popular solution for generating documentation from JavaDoc style comments, but the syntax is quite restrictive and it has not been updated in nearly 3 years.

[SfApexDoc](https://gitlab.com/StevenWCox/sfapexdoc/wikis/home) is an updated version with slightly less restrictive syntax and a number of other enhancements, its also being actively developed (albeit slowly).