# How would I set up Doxygen to document Apex Code?

Tags: contentdocument, documentation

Currently I'm in a situation where I'd like to add documentation support for my code using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). I've downloaded and installed the program and I have all of my .cls files in a single folder.

I am currently running the Doxygen source search directly in the file. I have also added .cls to the files to search. However when I run Doxygen, all of my pages are like so:

[image]

Completely empty. It doesn't sanitize the code (remove comments, highlight, etc.), and documentation indicators do not work even though the source is documentable, and commented such that it should be parsed. **How does one set up Doxygen to properly interpret and generate documentation?**

Comment: Might be worth looking into [ApexDoc](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/ApexDoc), as well as [this meta thread](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2252/documentation-strategy-template?cb=1).

Comment: It's an old question, but [this other question on using Doxygen w/Apex](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/925/documenting-salesforce-com-apex-class-files) may contain your answers.

Comment: @DerekF all I find there is 1 answer and a bunch of people telling the OP how good the *other* platform is

Comment: @tuskiomi The takeaway I got from it was that while Apex is a Java-like language, it is different enough that Doxygen can't really handle it.